# How to add additional currency characters in Spacy

Tags: python, spacy

I have documents where the character `\u0080` is used as a Euro. I want to add these and other characters to the currency symbol list so that the money entity gets picked up by the Spacy NER. What is the best way to deal with this?

Additionally I also have cases where money is represented as `CAD 5,000` and these are not picked by the NER as Money. What is the best way to deal with this situation, training the NER or adding `CAD` as a currency symbol?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1. The `'u\0080'` problem**

First thing first, it seems that the interpretation of the `'u\0080'` character depends on the platform you are using, it doesn't print on a Windows 7 machine but it works on a Linux machine...

For completeness, I have assumed that you get your text from an html document containing the `'&#x80;'` escape sequence (which should print as `€` in a browser), the `'\u0080'` character and some other arbitrary symbols we identify as currencies.

Before passing the text content to spaCy, we can call `html.unescape` which will take care of translating `&#x80;` to `€`, which in turn is going to be recognized by the default configuration as a currency.

```
text_html = ("I just found out that CAD 1,000 is about 641.3 &#x80. "
             "Some people call it 641.3 \u0080. "
             "Fantastic! But in the U.K. I'd rather pay 344 or \U0001F33B56.")

text = html.unescape(text_html)
```

Second, if there are symbols that are not recognized as a currency, like  and  for example, then we can change the `Defaults` of the language we use to qualify them as currencies.

That consists in replacing the `lex_attr_getters[IS_CURRENCY]` function by a custom one which holds a list of symbols describing a currency.

```
def is_currency_custom(text):
    # Stripping punctuation
    table = str.maketrans({key: None for key in string.punctuation})
    text = text.translate(table)

    all_currencies = ["\U0001F385", "\U0001F33B", "\u0080", "CAD"]
    if text in all_currencies:
        return True
    return is_currency_original(text)

# Keep a reference to the original is_currency function
is_currency_original = EnglishDefaults.lex_attr_getters[IS_CURRENCY]
# Assign a new function for IS_CURRENCY
EnglishDefaults.lex_attr_getters[IS_CURRENCY] = is_currency_custom
```

**2. The `CAD 5,000` problem**

For this one, a simple solution would be to define a special case. We say to the tokenizer that, wherever it meets `CAD`, this is a special case and it needs to do as instructed by us. We can set the `IS_CURRENCY` flag amongst other things.

```
special_case = [{
        ORTH: u'CAD', 
        TAG: u'$', 
        IS_CURRENCY: True}]

nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case(u'CAD', special_case)
```

Note that this is not perfect as you may get false positives. Imagine a document from an Canadian company selling CAD drawing services... So this is good but not great.

If we want to be more precise, we can create a `Matcher` object that will look for patterns like `CURRENCY[SPACE]NUMBER` or `NUMBER[SPACE]CURRENCY` and associate the `MONEY` entity with it.

```
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

MONEY = nlp.vocab.strings['MONEY']

# This is the matcher callback that sets the MONEY entity
def add_money_ent(matcher, doc, i, matches):
    match_id, start, end = matches[i]
    doc.ents += ((MONEY, start, end),)

matcher.add(
    'MoneyRedefined', 
    add_money_ent,
    [{'IS_CURRENCY': True}, {'IS_SPACE': True, 'OP': '?'}, {'LIKE_NUM': True}],
    [{'LIKE_NUM': True}, {'IS_SPACE': True, 'OP': '?'}, {'IS_CURRENCY': True}]
)
```

and you apply it to your `doc` object with `matcher(doc)`. The `'OP'` key makes the pattern optional, by allowing it to match 0 or 1 times.

**3. The full code**

```
import spacy
from spacy.symbols import IS_CURRENCY
from spacy.lang.en import EnglishDefaults
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
from spacy import displacy
import html
import string


def is_currency_custom(text):
    # Stripping punctuation
    table = str.maketrans({key: None for key in string.punctuation})
    text = text.translate(table)

    all_currencies = ["\U0001F385", "\U0001F33B", "\u0080", "CAD"]
    if text in all_currencies:
        return True
    return is_currency_original(text)

# Keep a reference to the original is_currency function
is_currency_original = EnglishDefaults.lex_attr_getters[IS_CURRENCY]
# Assign a new function for IS_CURRENCY
EnglishDefaults.lex_attr_getters[IS_CURRENCY] = is_currency_custom

nlp = spacy.load('en')

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

MONEY = nlp.vocab.strings['MONEY']

# This is the matcher callback that sets the MONEY entity
def add_money_ent(matcher, doc, i, matches):
    match_id, start, end = matches[i]
    doc.ents += ((MONEY, start, end),)

matcher.add(
    'MoneyRedefined', 
    add_money_ent,
    [{'IS_CURRENCY': True}, {'IS_SPACE': True, 'OP': '?'}, {'LIKE_NUM': True}],
    [{'LIKE_NUM': True}, {'IS_SPACE': True, 'OP': '?'}, {'IS_CURRENCY': True}]
)

text_html = ("I just found out that CAD 1,000 is about 641.3 &#x80. "
             "Some people call it 641.3 \u0080. "
             "Fantastic! But in the U.K. I'd rather pay 344 or \U0001F33B56.")

text = html.unescape(text_html)

doc = nlp(text)

matcher(doc)

displacy.serve(doc, style='ent')
```

This gives the expected:

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I just had one clarification, instead of using the Matcher, if I start to train the NER for CAD ... like entities would that be better?

Comment: Always a pleasure. My opinion is that it is better to keep the statistical approach of NER for more complex patterns. I consider implementing a matcher much faster than training a model, but you may find reasons to do otherwise.

Comment: By the way I noticed this is your first question on SO. You can [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it has worked for you.